# Regular expressions tutorials

Tags: regex

Is there a regular expression tutorial that doesn't use a designer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I learned the basics of RegEx with [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html)
It talks about what happens behind the scenes and doesn't depend on a certain platform.

Comment: I started with the same tutorial.  Knowing the .Net Framework Regex support specifically isn't bad either.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is a great and quick getting started guide:

[The absolute bare minimum every programmer should know about regular expressions](http://immike.net/blog/2007/04/06/the-absolute-bare-minimum-every-programmer-should-know-about-regular-expressions/)

Comment: dead link, can you please update?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) I have used it in the past to build my RegEx. It is good to help learning too. Not really a tutorial but you can test out regex's with it.

Comment: That looks pretty cool and simple but I like learning the old school way :-)

Answer (score 0):

[RegEx Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), while also not a tutorial in itself, has been one of the best tools for me. The on the fly highlighting helps.

Answer (score 0):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is also nice, if I may add. There is a variety of similr tools available. A simple google search "regex tool" reveals most of them.
As far as for the tutorial, I can recommend the book ["Mastering Regular Expressions"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570/) (I read the first, there is probably a newer edition by now)